# Product ring isomorphism from example 11.6.3 in Artin's Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, finite-fields, ring-isomorphism

I am currently reading chapter 11.6 in Artin's Algebra on Product Rings. There's a proposition that says if $e$ is an idempotent element of a ring $S$ and $e' = 1 -e$ then $S \cong eS \times e'S$. I am struggling with an example I'm hoping to get help:

> Example 11.6.3: Let $R'$ be obtained by adjoining an element $\delta$
>   to $\mathbb{F}_{11}$ with the relation $\delta^2-3=0$. Its elements
>   are the $11^2$ linear combinations $a+b\delta$, with $a,b \in \mathbb{F}_{11}$ and $\delta^2=3$. This is not a field since
>   $\mathbb{F}_{11}$ contains two square roots $\pm5$ of $3$. The
>   elements $e = \delta -5$ and $e'=-\delta-5$ are idempotents in $R'$.
>   Therefore $R'$ is isomorphic to the product $eR'\times e'R'$.

(*So far I am able to understand until here. But I don't understand the rest*). Parentheses mine below.

> Since the order of $R'$ is $11^2$, $|eR|=|e'R'|=11$ (*I don't see
>   why*). The rings $eR'$ and $e'R'$ are both isomorphic to
>   $\mathbb{F}_{11}$ (*bigger why*), and $R'$ is isomorphic to the
>   product ring $\mathbb{F}_{11} \times \mathbb{F}_{11}$. (*This is given
>   from the last two sentences*).

What should I do to see the above? I know that $eR'$ and $e'R'$ are ideals of $R'$. If their orders are $11$ then I could try to construct an isomorphism for the second sentence. But how do I see that they have $11$ element each in $eR'$ and $e'R'$?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, the ring $R'$ is isomorphic to $eR'\times e'R'$, and $|R'|=11\times11$. It follows that
$$|eR'|\times|e'R'|=|R'|=11\times11,$$
So $|eR'|=11^a$ and $|e'R'|=11^b$ for some nonnegative integers $a$ and $b$ with $a+b=2$.

Of course $0,e\in eR'$ and $0,e'\in e'R'$, where $e\neq0$ and $e'\neq0$, so $|eR'|>1$ and $|e'R'|>1$. Hence 
$$|eR'|=|e'R'|=11.$$

It follows that both $eR'$ and $e'R'$ are isomorphic to $\Bbb{F}_{11}$, because that is the unique ring (up to isomorphism) of $11$ elements. More generally, the unique ring (up to isomorphism) of $p$ elements is $\Bbb{F}_p$ whenever $p$ is prime.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just to confirm that I get it correct, since $eR'$, $e'R'$ are ideals of $R'$, their order must divide the ring $R'$ and hence they can only be $1, 11, $ or $11^2$. Then from the fact that $R' \cong eR' \times e'R'$, we have $|R'| = |eR'|\cdot |e'R'|$. And then we can deduce the order of each is $11$ since neither is the zero ring. And since they are rings, there's only one of order 11 and so they are isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{11}$?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly right. Though in general, if you know that $A\cong B\times C$ then also $|A|=|B|\times|C|$, so this in fact *proves* that the orders of $B$ and $C$ divide the order of $A$.

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you! The book skipped a couple of steps and that threw me off.

Answer (score 1):

For the cardinality you note that $11^2=\vert R'\vert = \vert eR'\vert \cdot \vert r R'\vert$. There are not many factorisations of $11^2$ as $11$ is prime. Both $eR'$ and $rR'$ are finite integral domains and hence fields. All fields of order $11$ are isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{11}$.

Comment: Thank you! I am able to understand this now.